# Magento connect not working

Tags: magento

I am using 2.0 magneto connect. I am trying to update magneto 1.7 to 1.8. When i add "http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Mage_All_Latest" and click install i am getting an error "Connection Error try again later." . I also removed the "http//" from the extension URL but its giving the same error. and when i click on "check for update" button. its does not show result. Just a blank page is displayed with title"Manage Existing Extensions" I was thinking that there may be some bug. I just on the development mode on and change the index file accordingly but there is no error. I did lot of R & D on this but did not get success.  [image]

Kindly check screenshot for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

Yup, used the 2.0 extension straight from the “Get Extension Key” section.  that will work

[image]